# No module named google.cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm using python 3.7, I am working with google cloud automl vision, after training the model I want to test it through python , I copied the code there

```
from google.cloud import automl
```

I have installed all the available libraries for google cloud but still it is giving me this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'

can anyone please help me? I will be really thankful

Comment: What libraries did you install?  How did you install them?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `pip install google-cloud-automl`?

Is this installed in the same env that you have running if you are using pyenv or conda

I just tested this in a new conda env with this active and then installing i can load the module :)

Comment: thank God, I have find someone with loading module, I have pip virtual environment, I have installed all these libraries, with pip and some of them with conda, but still getting this error, can u please specifically guide me like what environment are you using, I mean pip or conda? and how did u install the libraries like by conda package or pip ? thanks

Comment: yeah I activate the virtual environment using "activate" and than installed the libraries in it, at the end with same environment I launched jupyter notebook and execute the code, it give module error.

Answer (score 0):

ok so after like hours I found the solution, the problem was with `google-core-api` I have installed it using

> conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 google-cloud-core
> you can find more commands in https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/google-cloud-core.

after this i was getting an error " ImportError: cannot import name 'automl_v1beta1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location) "

so i have tried to install automl with

> conda install -c conda-forge google-cloud-automl
> it did installed successfully , that error solves too, but then i was getting this error " module has no attribute [streamUanry_call]. this was because of installing too much libraries it messed up the whole environment, so i have created fresh new environment and just installed two libraries along with some important libraries like "django, etc" .
> the two libraries i have installed were:

```
google-core-api
```

from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/google-cloud-core
with:

> conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 google-cloud-core

the other library was `googl-cloud-automl`
I have installed it with

> conda install -c conda-forge google-cloud-automl

and there it is finally the whole importing worked and executed my program.